# javascript .onclick how do i hide other .onclick options

Tags: php, javascript

Ok I'm using a code to overlay a photo above a video, meaning, the div with the video in it is hidden until someone clicks the photo. Here is the code i'm using.

```
<img src="http://ericavain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ravaughn.jpg" alt="ravaughn" width="610" height="390" class="aligncenter image" />
<div class="videobox" style="display:none;">
<iframe width="610" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rpVctT8BuVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and here is the script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.image').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.videobox').show()
        $('.videobox')[0].play();
    });
});
</script>
```

The way I have that code set up is, if anyone clicks a photo that has the class `.image` then the photo will disappear and the video will be displayed.

Ok now the problem is, if I have more than one post on the home page using the `.image` class, and someone clicks on the photo of the first post, then it makes the image disappear for the second post as that has the same class well.

Is there a way that i can do this so that when then person clicks on that image of that post it disappears, instead of it making all images that have the class `.image` disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more code? Meanwhile you could try this

```
$(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        var video = $(this).next('.videobox');
        $(this).hide();
        video.show()
        video[0].play();
    });
});
```

this way, you work with the next `.videobox` to that image. A cleaner way would be use the `data` property to link the image to the videos, or putting them on a same container.

Comment: yes but the video doesn't show at all now, the image hises which is right but now the video is also hidden @martriay

Comment: what line do i add that to and do i erase a lin @martriay

Comment: That didn't work lol, plus the `.videobox' is not in that and it should be lol @martriay

Comment: what about `console.log($(this).next())` ?

Comment: Idk what's going on the videos are not showing at all lol, the `.videobox` div isn't even coming up lol i think it has to do with this line `video.show()` i'm pulling from youtube, shouldn't that be a class object

Comment: again, could you provide more code? certainly there is more html in here

Comment: I added the css of the video box @martriay